# Find commonly occurring sequences in a string

Tags: java, algorithm

How can I find commonly occurring sequences in a string in Java?

The string is a long sequence of digits and I want to find the most commonly occurring sequences of digits.

Comment: What is your desired result for "1111"?

Comment: I think 1x 1111, 2x 111, 3x11. But that doesn't really matter, I only need to find the most common sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that depends on how long the sequences are that you are looking for.

What I would do is use a [Guava `Multiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), iterate over the sequence, write all subsequences to the Multiset and sort that by occurrence. Here's a sample implementation:

```
public static String getMostFrequentSequence(final String input, final int patternLength) {
    final Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
    final int length = patternLength < 0 ? input.length() : Math.min(patternLength, input.length());
    for (int l = 2; l < length; l++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < input.length() - l; o++) {
            multiset.add(input.substring(o, o + l));
        }
    }
    return Ordering.from(new Comparator<Entry<String>>() {
        public int compare(final Entry<String> o1, final Entry<String> o2) {
            return
            ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(o1.getCount(), o2.getCount())
            .compare(o1.getElement(), o2.getElement())
            .result();
        }
    }).max(multiset.entrySet()).getElement();
}
```

And about performance: This test method takes about a second on my machine for unlimited length and about 25 milliseconds when I limit the pattern length to 12 chars

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        sb.append(random.nextInt(10));
    }
    final long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final String input = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println(getMostFrequentSequence(input, -1));
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1);
    final long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(getMostFrequentSequence(input, 12));
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t2);
}
```

Comment: I would expect the highest count to be a 2 digit number.  Using this approach, you don't need to do longer strings. esp if the string is random. ;)

Comment: @Peter I know, but what should you do with specs as vague as these? :-)

Comment: +1: for an interesting solution and effort. IMHO, its only meaningful to compare strings of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

For a given length of numbers, you could place then all in an ArrayList, sort them and count the number of duplicates (they will be next to each other) You will always have less than 1000 entries.